# Create a Scoreboard in Javascript for a Math Quiz

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a Math Quiz using Javascript. I am having trouble creating a "scoreboard." I need to show the user how many questions they have answered so far and the total score. Also, for my Question #5, I am trying to make it a "Narrative Question with a Text Response." I need to have at least 3 types of questions. So far, I have radio buttons for multiple choice and a textbox for a fill-in-the blank question.

Here is my JS file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Math Quiz!</title>
<link href ="quizCSS.css" rel ="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<script src = "MathQuiz.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function myAnswer1(){
let question1= document.querySelector("#textbox").value; 
if(question1 == 4){
alert("You are correct!");
}
else{
alert("Wrong answer!");
}
}
</script>

<script>
function myAnswer2(){

let question2 = document.querySelector('input[name="question2"]:checked').value;
if(question2 == 9){
alert("You are correct!");
}
else{
alert("Wrong answer!");
}
}
</script>

<script>
function myAnswer3(){

let question3 = document.querySelector('input[name="question3"]:checked').value;
if(question3 == 5){
alert("You are correct!");
}
else{
alert("Wrong answer!");
}
}
</script>

<script>
function myAnswer4(){

let question3 = document.querySelector('input[name="question4"]:checked').value;
if(question3 == 9){
alert("You are correct!");
}
else{
alert("Wrong answer!");
}
}

<script>
function myAnswer5(){

let question5 = document.querySelector('input[name="question5"]:checked').value;
if(question5 == https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Blue_Square.svg" width="100" height="100){
alert("You are correct!");
}
else{
alert("Wrong answer!");
}
}


</script>
</head>


<body>
<h1>Take the Quiz!</h1>

<form id = "quiz" name = "quiz">

<div id="q1">
<p class = "questions">1) What is 2 + 2?</p>
<input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "question1">
<input type="button" onclick="myAnswer1()" value="Submit Answer">
</div>





<input type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Start Question 1">
<script>
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "block";
}
</script>


<div id="q2">
<p class = "questions">2) What is 3 to the power of 2?</p>
<input type = "radio" id = "mc1" name = "question2" value = "9">9<br>
<input type = "radio" id = "mc2" name = "question2" value = "6">6<br>
<input type = "radio" id = "mc3" name = "question2" value = "3">3<br>
<input type="button" onclick="myAnswer2()" value="Submit Answer">
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction2()" value="Start Question 2">
<script>
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("q2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<div id="q3">
<p class = "questions">3) What is the square root of 25?</p>

<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question3" value = "5"> 5<br>
<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question3" value = "525"> 525<br>
<input type="button" onclick="myAnswer3()" value="Submit Answer">
</div>


<input type="button" onclick="myFunction3()" value="Start Question 3">
<script>
function myFunction3() {
  document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q2").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<div id="q4">
<p class = "questions">4) What is the square root of 81?</p>

<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question4" value = "9"> 9<br>
<input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question4" value = "7"> 7<br>
<input type="button" onclick="myAnswer4()" value="Submit Answer">
</div>


<input type="button" onclick="myFunction4()" value="Start Question 4">
<script>
function myFunction4() {
  document.getElementById("q4").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<div id="q5">
<p class = "questions">5) The Joker has a dirty bomb somewhere in Gotham city. Batman has 1 hour before it detonates and leaves the city polluted with Joker toxin for months to come. Batman beat the location of the bomb out of Harley Quinn. It is 10 miles away. The bomb would take 30 minutes to diffuse. If Batman drives the Batmobile at 100mph, how long would it take to reach and diffuse the Joker toxin bomb?</p>

<input type = "image" id = "pic1" name = "question5" value = img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Blue_Square.svg" width="100" height="100"><br>
<input type = "image" id = "pic2" name = "question5" value = img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Green_equilateral_triangle_point_up.svg" width="100" height="100"><br>
<input type = "image" id = "pic3" name = "question5" value = img src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/310000/velka/red-circle.png" width="100" height="100"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myAnswer5()" value="Submit Answer">
</div>


<input type="button" onclick="myFunction5()" value="Start Question 5">
<script>
function myFunction5() {
  document.getElementById("q5").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("q4").style.display = "none";
}
</script>


<input id = "button" type = "button" value = "I'm finished!" onclick = "check();">


</form>

<div id = "after_submit">
<p id = "number_correct"></p>
<p id = "message"></p>
<img id = "picture">
</div>

<script src = "MathQuiz.js" defer></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Here is my HTML

```
function check(){

    var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;
    var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;
    var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;
    var question4 = document.quiz.question4.value;
    var question5 = document.quiz.question5.value;
    var correct = 0;

    if (question1 == "4") {
        correct++;
}
    if (question2 == "9") {
        correct++;
}   
    if (question3 == "5") {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question4 == "9") {
        correct++;
}   
    if (question5 == "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Blue_Square.svg") {
        correct++;
    }


    var pictures = ["img/win.gif", "img/meh.jpeg", "img/lose.gif"];
    var messages = ["You pass the quiz", "You fail the quiz"];
    var result = ["Correct!", "Wrong Answer!"];
    var correct = "Correct!";
    var wrong = "Wrong Answer!";
    var score;

    if (correct == 0) {
        score = 4;
    }

    if (correct > 0 && correct < 3) {
        score = 3;
    }

    if (correct == 3) {
        score = 2;
    }

    if (correct == 4) {
        score = 1;
    }

    if (correct == 5) {
        score = 0;
    }


    document.getElementbyId("correct").innerHTML = correct;
    document.getElementbyId("wrong").innerHTML = wrong;
    document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[score];
    document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "You got " + correct + " correct.";
    document.getElementById("picture").src = pictures[score];
    }
```

Comment: Please try to focus the problem by asking one question. Also edit the question so the html matches the html and the js matches the js. Also let us know what you've tried re a specific problem.

Comment: "Here is my HTML" you do know that is JavaScript and not HTML right?.  I believe there a s good bit of work required here to achieve a clear, functional solution.  For example in your first code example you have multiple `<script>` tags when only one with all your script in it would suffice.

Comment: There is no reason to load script twice `<script src = "MathQuiz.js" defer></script>`

Comment: I believe you are totally confusing yourself by mixing multiple `<script></script>` in with your HTML, certainly it does make reading this and helping you much more effort.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `check()` function, you called `document.getElementbyId()` twice instead of `document.getElementById()` and you might want to change the values of your image inputs

---

And I have to add that I think you need to you need to review your code. There are much easier ways to  achieve what you wish to achieve.